# Volumetric lighting scene

Tags: node-editor, light, lighting, volumetrics

[image]

Hello everyoane.
What settings should to apply to the light point to create in blender a scene light this?
I come with a past in Cinema 4D, there was very easy, just set the visible light to Volumetric and set the intensity, but how does this work in blender?
I have searching for an answer here, but nothing matches with what I need...
Kind Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for stating your question clearly.
You need to setup a world environment mist.
The rendered light volume in Cycles doesn´t work with (noise/volumes)on the **light**. It works with noise /volumes on the space (**Enviroment**) like in the real world.
Make a cube. Assign a shader to it. Edit the shader. Delete diffuse node, CTRL+Shift A, search for principled volume. Attach it to the Material output on the VOLUME input connector.
Shift+A, select NOISE. Plug that NOISE into the DENSITY connector of the principled volume shader.
Delete all lights in the scene.
Make the world from the world property tab: black color.
Drive your camera inside the box you previously created and that you´ve assigned the principled volume shader.
Inside that box and with the camera looking through, create a ppoint light. Give it energy of 100. And continue to drop it down by half on each render test: (50, 25, 12, 7, 3.5...etc)
Until your light energy is appropiate for the effect you´re looking for.

Thank you for your consideration to vote me as the answer by clicking to the left :the icon with a check mark and upvote this answer.

BFCT_Schiller